# Number of ways to create a spiral array

Tags: arrays, algorithm

We have an array with values [2,1,5,3,7] and we have to find number of ways to form a spiral array by deleting one element at a time. Lets say when we remove 2 we can have [1,5,3,7] and when we remove 1 then we have [2,5,3,7]. There is no more possibility. so we should return 2. Do you have any idea how can i solve this problem in Java?

Comment: What exactly is a spiral array?

Comment: a[0] < a[1]>a[2]<a[3]

Comment: Seems `zigzag array` is more common term.

Comment: divide the arrays into correct spiral chunks and see what is between them